# How a static method get context from the calling activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I am using `MPAndroidChart` lib to plot graph, and i got some problem in using with the marketview the code are below :

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    View p = findViewById(R.id.pie);
    ChartPie.Plot(p, p.getId());


    View l = findViewById(R.id.line);
    ChartLine.Plot(l, l.getId());

}
```

**Chartline.java**

```
protected Context context;


public static void Plot(View v, int id){

    LineChart lineChart = v.findViewById(id);

    HelloME mv = new HelloME(**context**, R.layout.mymarketview);
    mv.setChartView(lineChart);
    lineChart.setMarker(mv);

    XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                    ...
```

**HelloME.java**

```
    private TextView tvContent;

    public HelloME(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    }
```

I dont know how to get the **context** in the class Chartline, because the method is in static. All the code is copy from the example in the lib, but i am trying to separate the linechart class, and face this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are several types of context. In your case you can get it from `v.getContext();`

Answer (score 1):

Modify HelloME.java like below:-

```
private TextView tvContent;
private static Context context_; 

  public HelloME(Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);
    context_ = context;
    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
}
public static Context getContext(){
    return context_;
}
```

Now in Chartline.java

```
 HelloME mv = new HelloME(HelloME.getContext(), R.layout.mymarketview);
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9577784/pp-chan , you can follow this answer , or you can use Base Context or getApplicationContext()

Comment: it doesnt work, this cause some runtime error, stop my app

Comment: Your `HelloME.java` class object must be instantiated before Chartline.java's object